# C - next_prime function fails on occasion when limited by if(input=prime) is used

Tags: c, function, primes

This code fails on certain primes (7, 13, 19..) but works on different ones (5, 11, 17..). Without the prime condition it works everytime, as well as does the is_prime function. Did I write the condition badly? It should return next prime if input number is prime and return -1 when it is not.

```
int next_prime(int prime) {
    int c;
    if(is_prime(prime) == 0)
        return -1;
    if(prime < 2)
        c = 2;
    else if (prime == 2)
        c = 3;
    else if(prime & 1){
        prime += 2;
        c = is_prime(prime) ? prime : next_prime(prime);
    } else
        c = next_prime(prime-1);

    return c;
}
```

Edit: `is_prime` worked on all tried numbers, I believe it is correct.

```
int is_prime(int num){
    if(num == 1)
        return 0;
    if((num & 1)==0)
        return num == 2;
    else {
        int i, limit = sqrt(num);
        for (i = 3; i <= limit; i+=2){
            if (num % i == 0)
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: your code is very contrived. if `is_prime(prime)` and it is not 2, it is odd; and the next prime is also odd.

Comment: Please make clear what `next_prime`  is supposed to do. I think I've guessed, but the question would be clearer if you'd tell us everything. Also are you sure the `is_prime` function works correctly?

Comment: `next_prime` returns nearest prime number bigger then input, but only when the input is a prime number (7 should give 11, 11 should give 13 an so on). Otherwise it should return -1.

Comment: Execute `next_prime(7)` on paper and see what happens. But anyway your `next_prime` is overly complicated anyway.

Comment: 9 is not a prime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `next_prime` function is somewhat weird and overly complicated, why don't you just use this:

```
int next_prime(int prime) {
  while (!is_prime(++prime))
  {
  }    
  return prime;
}
```

This happens in your `next_prime` function:

Let's suppose you call `next_prime(7)`:

```
int next_prime(int prime) {
  int c;
  if (is_prime(prime) == 0)
    return -1;
  if (prime < 2)
    c = 2;
  else if (prime == 2)
    c = 3;
  else if (prime & 1) {
    prime += 2;
    c = is_prime(prime) ? prime : next_prime(prime);
  }
  else
    c = next_prime(prime - 1);

  return c;
}
```

None of the first three tests is true, to we end up at `else if (prime & 1)`. This test is true, so following lines will be executed:

```
prime += 2;   // prime becomes 9 (7 + 2)
```

`is_prime(9)` is false so you execute `next_prime(9)`

```
c = is_prime(prime) ? prime : next_prime(prime);
```

and `next_prime(9)` will obviously return -1.

You could have found out that yourself by using a debugger.

Comment: Thank you! Can't belive how simple the code may have been, I feel dumb for overcomplicating mine:/

Comment: @Mori Hint: there is still room for optimisation in my version. I let you find out yourself.

Comment: I know this is dumb and all.. but I am pretty new to C and did not know I can use debugger on functions..  could you maybe link an article on how to do so? Thank you:)

Comment: @Mori no, because it depends totally on your platform which you didn't specify.

Comment: Oh, my bad.. I am using the terminal emulator on Oracle VirtualBox running ubuntu.

Comment: @Mori that's not enough, you need to tell us if you use gcc, if you use an IDE or if you compile launching `gcc yourprog.c` etc.

Comment: I am using gcc, c11.

Comment: Ok, thank you for everything! I will definitely look into both optimalization and debugging.. Have a nice day:)